# Sending 16 bit data in assembly x86 using serial ports

Tags: assembly, x86

I am making a multiplayer game that works on 2 pcs and he communication is via two com ports, The ideas is I want to send and receive 16 bit data but the highest value is 8, so I neeed to divide them but it is causing me errors

```
recieve proc
        mov data_in, 0 ; variable to store data
        mov dx , 03F8H 
        in al , dx 
        mov bl, al  
        mov byte ptr data_in, bl
        mov cx,200 ; just delay
        kk:loop kk
        mov dx , 03F8H
        in al , dx 
        mov bh, al  
        mov byte ptr data_in + 1, bh
        ret
recieve endp
```

```
transmit proc
        mov bl , byte ptr data_out
        
        mov dx , 03F8H
        mov al, bl
        out dx , al
        mov cx, 200
        kk:loop kk
        mov bl , byte ptr data_out + 1
        mov dx , 03F8H
        mov al, bl
        out dx , al
        
        ret
transmit endp
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by _causing me errors_? Aside: your code seems unnecessarily complex: why copy via `bh`/`bl` when you could use `al` directly?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I was just trying something, and by errors I mean the data is not transmitted correctly if It exceeds the size of one byte.

Comment: Instead of dividing the 16bit words receive/send them at once: `in ax,dx` `out dx,ax`.

Comment: @vitsoft Can this happen even if the configuration was set to handle 8 bits? and how I can update the configuration to be 16 bits?

Comment: @zizo In one of my old asm utility I've been using 16bit ports to configure USART on realmode DOS, so I hope so.

Comment: @vitsoft Do you have code or something?

Comment: How did you configure UARTs? Is FIFO enabled? In receiver,  do you poll Data Ready flag before read?

Comment: @vitsoft `out dx,ax` will out `al` to `03F8H` and `ah` to `03F9H`. Latter is not a data register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When receive is called, how does it know that data is available? It should check the receive data available flag before reading the receive holding register.

For the delay loop, instead of looping for a fixed number of iterations, it should read the receive data available flag to wait for the next byte to become available. 200 iterations is not nearly enough.

```
receive proc
        call receive_byte
        mov byte ptr data_in, al
        call receive_byte
        mov byte ptr data_in + 1, al
        ret
receive endp

receive_byte proc
    receive_wait:   
        mov dx, 03F8H + 5
        in al, dx
        test al, 1
        jz receive_wait

        mov dx, 03F8H
        in al, dx 
        ret
receive_byte endp
```

Transmit is similar, but it checks the transmit holding register empty flag.

```
transmit proc
        mov cl, byte ptr data_out
        call transmit_byte
        mov cl, byte ptr data_out + 1
        call transmit_byte
        ret
transmit endp

transmit_byte proc
    transmit_wait:
        mov dx, 03F8H + 5
        in al, dx
        test al, 1 << 5
        jz transmit_wait

        mov dx, 03f8H
        mov al, cl
        out dx, al
        ret
transmit_byte endp
```